# ArcGIS for WPF: LayerCanvas.ArrangeOverride Setting Invalid FrameworkElement Size

Tags: wpf, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I'm reposting this here from ESRI's ArcGIS for WPF Forum in hopes of getting some more exposure. Original post is **[here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/93002-LayerCanvas.ArrangeOverride-Setting-Invalid-FrameworkElement-Size-%28Crashes-App%29)**.

I'm intermittently experiencing an error when rapidly changing map scales on an ArcGIS WPF Map Control (v. 10.1.1) (i.e. from very large to very small, or vice-versa) wherein my application will crash. It appears that the LayerCanvas.ArrangeOverride is, for some reason, attempting to set an invalid Width property on the FrameworkElement's dependency property. Based on this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051823/unhandled-error-in-silverlight-application-code-4004-system-argumentexception)**, it appears that the issue was carried over from the Silverlight API.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and been able to work around it?

The following is a snippet of the stack trace with the offending method:

```
System.ArgumentException: '-907.750834278924' is not a valid value for property 'Width'.
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_Width(Double value)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.LayerCanvas.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this problem was in an ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.ElementLayer in the map which has an attached property for its envelope. If a negatively sized envelope gets passed up through to the layer, it is unhandled in ESRI's API. Inserting a check like below gets around the issue:

```
    Envelope arcGISEnvelope = new Envelope()
    {
        XMin = topLeftMap.X,
        YMin = bottomRightMap.Y,
        XMax = bottomRightMap.X,
        YMax = topLeftMap.Y
    };
    //Check here to prevent an unhandled ESRI exception.
    if (arcGISEnvelope.Width < 0 || arcGISEnvelope.Height < 0)
    {
       return;
    }
    this.imageControl.SetValue(ElementLayer.EnvelopeProperty, arcGISEnvelope);
```

This seems to only happen at very large map scales. In any event, I hope that this helps someone else down the road.